# Is it possible to publish versions of a page/asset in AEM?

Tags: aem

For a regulatory requirement, we are supposed to show the previous versions of a page/asset (state of page as of particular date) at publish instance. So when an end user searches an asset, and if the asset had multiple versions, he should be able to hit any version from the search result.

I managed this to solution from author instance wherein I included the versionId in query param or selector and a custom filter picked this version in url, used version manager to return the respective version of page.

When it comes to publish, from 6.1 [AEM has made ACLs stricter](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/release-notes/deprecated-removed-features.html) in accessing /jcr:system. I tried to publish a revision say /jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/1f/4f/d1/1f4fd128-b9e3-43cc-9d8a-9335bb34c3ae from activation tree and it didnt publish either.

With this requirement how can we publish versions of a page/asset?

Comment: i guess in publish instance for a page or asset there will be only version is required to showcase/present to end user. what is the usecase that you are looking for the multiple versions of asset to have available in publish environment.?

Comment: So our content authors keep updating the assets and publish them at regular interval. This is specific site targeting auditors and regulatory. They should have ability to view the asset as appeared 1 year back etc.